# Language model fine tuning BERT with run_language_modeling.py - Reduce memory usage?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am following instructions on this webpage (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/language-modeling) to fine tune the pretrained BERT model on my own corpus. I managed to run the example using the WikiText-103 dataset (https://s3.amazonaws.com/research.metamind.io/wikitext/wikitext-103-v1.zip) that, once unpacked, takes about 550MB. I managed to run this example with 48GB memory and a K80.

I then tried to do this using my own corpus, with is 20 times larger. I know that with the same hardware config it would not be possible, so I tested chunking my corpus into different equal sizes to figure out what would be the maximum corpus size that the language model fine tuning can run on a 128GB memory + K80 setting.

As indicated in the comment below, I also used the following settings:

- use_fast=True to use a 'faster' tokenizer
- toggle '--line_by_line'

But with these settings, the maximum corpus I can fit is a 3.5GB chunk, for 128GB memory and K80. Beyond this, the program stops with OOM when it is doing `INFO - transformers.data.datasets.language_modeling -   Creating features from dataset file`, i.e., it has not even started the GPU processing yet.

I would like to understand a little how the language model fine tuning code works - what is the dataset-memory ratio, and if it is possible to configure it so it does not use so much memory for processing the dataset.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please modify the script (lines 196 and 198) and add `use_fast=True` to the AutoTokenizer generation.

Comment: Thanks, I have done it and restarted the process. I also noticed that you can use a parameter 'line-by-line', would that help too?

Comment: I have just updated the question. I have done some experimentation with a higher memory and those two parameters set properly. But still, you need it to work on small chunks of data. Can't understand how it works...